# How to make HttpClient.PostAsync work the same way as post from Postman?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

When I post to my API (written in .NET core and hosted on Linux) from Postman, everything works as expected. When I do the same from code (using HttpClient), the parameters do not get sent. Below my code:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new []
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(nameof(userName), userName),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(nameof(serialNumber), serialNumber)
});

var result = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```

In my opinion content should get sent and everything should be alright. I see significant differences between the calls in Wireshark.

Working POST from Postman:
[image: Working POST from Postman]
POST from HttpClient that does not work:
[image: POST from HttpClient that does not work]
.

What can I do to make sure that my HttpClient.PostAsync sends the data correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Postman version doesn't have a body, but it has `userName` and `serialNumber` encoded into the url as query parameters.

In order to achieve the same using `HttpClient`, you need to add those parameters to the url.

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(_uri);

// If you already have query parameters, this code will preserve them. 
// Otherwise you can just create a new NameValueCollection instance.
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
parameters[nameof(userName)] = userName;
parameters[nameof(serialNumber)] = serialNumber;

uriBuilder.Query = parameters.ToString();

// Pass null as HttpContent to make HttpClient send an empty body
var result = await _httpClient.PostAsync(uriBuilder.ToString(), null).ConfigureAwait(false);
```